# Script to either rotate existing text element or insert graphic element

Tags: python, arcgis-10.1, cartography

I have about 300 maps that contain a text element that needs to be rotated.  I am pretty new to python but I have heard how great it is.  This seemed like the perfect task for python but I have had no luck finding any examples on how to do this.  The text is "Figure 1-1" and it just needs to be rotated 90 degrees and moved to a set location in the corner.  If rotating is not an option I thought I could just manually rotate the text and save it as a graphic and then write a script that would insert the graphic in the desired location.  This also doesnt seem possible.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange!  Could you let us know what mapping software you are using?

Comment: I am using ArcGIS 10.1

Answer (score 1):

I haven't played with text elements much yet, but you need to use the [arcpy.mapping](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s300000032000000) module to manipulate [TextElement objects](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s30000000m000000).  You can change the position by adjusting the text element's `elementPositionX` and `elementPositionY` properties.  As of now, it looks like there's no way to programatically rotate the layout elements.  There's an [open ArcGIS Idea](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087E00000004Qe6&returnUrl=/apex/ideaList?c=09a300000004xET&category=Maps%2band%2bContent&sort=recent) for this, so you should put your vote in!